# ESP32: pin description and peripheral configuration

Tags: datasheet, esp32

In the [datasheet](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32_datasheet_en.pdf) of ESP32, Table 1 "Pin description" there is the list of all pins and their function. For example, let's see the UART ones:

```
GPIO16     25 I/O GPIO16, HS1_DATA4, U2RXD, EMAC_CLK_OUT
GPIO17     27 I/O GPIO17, HS1_DATA5, U2TXD, EMAC_CLK_OUT_180
SD_DATA_2  28 I/O GPIO9, HS1_DATA2, U1RXD ,SD_DATA2, SPIHD
SD_DATA_3  29 I/O GPIO10, HS1_DATA3, U1TXD, SD_DATA3, SPIWP 
U0RXD      40 I/O GPIO3, U0RXD, CLK_OUT2
U0TXD      41 I/O GPIO1, U0TXD, CLK_OUT3, EMAC_RXD2
```

But in Table 10 "Peripheral Pin Configurations", I read:

```
UART  U0RXD_in    Any GPIO Pins
      U0TXD_out
      U1RXD_in
      U1TXD_out
      U2RXD_in
      U2TXD_out
```

(note: for clarity I removed the flow-control pins)

**What does the first table actually mean?**

It cannot be the "default" function, because for each pin are listed several functions.
From the second table I assume I can configure each UART function to any GPIO pin.

May I rely on the second table? I mean, I really can assign UART, I2C, SPI, etc... to *any* GPIO as stated?

Answer (score 1):

You need to read about the IO_MUX function in the [Technical Reference Manual](http://espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32_technical_reference_manual_en.pdf). For complex processors like this it is not uncommon to split the pinout and parametric characteristics into a "datasheet" and put the functional information in a "technical reference manual".

Comment: If I understand correcly, we can summarize as: "GPIO Matrix (see Table 10) allows to configure almost any pin to almost any peripheral, but some specific high-performance features needs to by-pass this. Hence, IO_MUX is less flexible (see Table 1) but allows to directly connect the pin to the related internal hardware".

Comment: In other words, if I'm interested in standard UARTs like the example above, relying on GPIO Matrix I can map them to any GPIO. It remains to be seen if the Arduino framework handles this automagically...